# My formula works in one cell but returns FALSE in another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to perform a calculation and the first IF(OR) condition is giving me the right answer, but the second and third IF(OR) conditions are returning "FALSE" instead of a number.

Cell A23 is a dropdown list of products.

Below is my formula.  What am I doing wrong?

```
=IF(OR(A23="ICS OTT",A23="ICS UI"),ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/250*(1+$B$7)),
IF(OR(A23="ICS+VCS UI"),ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/180*(1+$B$7)),
IF(A23="VCS Apps",ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$6/180*1+$B$7),
"NA"))))))
```

Comment: Check A23 to ensure the spelling is exactly the same with out any extra spaces.

Comment: You have an "or" on the second line that doesn't have more than one option. I'd also use the formula eval to see where it's failing.

Comment: Everything is in the initial IF statement's `value_if_true` so anything that doesn't match `OR(A23="ICS OTT",A23="ICS UI")` will yield `FALSE`. You also don't have `num_digits` for the roundups...

Comment: checked A23 to ensure all spelling and spacing is exact. Thank you for pointing out the extra "or" in the 2nd line. Is it possible to nest IF statements with ROUNDUP?  My modification (below) is resulting in an error assuming I don't want a formula.  Can someone help me with my formula?                                                                                                       =IF(OR(A23="ICS OTT",A23="ICS UI"),ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/250*(1+$B$7),0),
IF((A23="ICS+VCS UI"),ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/180*(1+$B$7),0),
IF(A23="VCS Apps",ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$6/180*1+$B$7),0),"NA"
"NA"))))))

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a parameter in your `ROUNDUP` function -- it's expecting a second parameter for the precision of the rounding.  Assuming you are rounding to a whole number, this should do the trick:

```
=if(OR(A23="ICS OTT",A23="ICS UI"),ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/250*(1+$B$7)),0),
  if(A23="ICS+VCS UI",ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$5/180*1+$B$7),0),
    if(A23="VCS Apps",ROUNDUP(($B$3*$B$6/180*1+$B$7),0),
      "NA")))
```